# Datalabels on Highmaps appearing bottom to top

Tags: svg, highcharts

I am facing a strange problem with Highmaps. I have a geojson map that Highmaps shows properly. Mouseover works and tooltips appear in the correct places. However, when I turn on data labels, they appear upside down. That is, a label that should appear near the bottom of the map (centered on its province) now appears near the top, and vice-versa. **The data labels' coordinate system seems to be reversed.**

[image: Highmaps data labels]

In the image, the label "603863" should appear over the bottom-most province, while "1966085" should appear over the topmost province.

A sample of my geojson data:

```
var provincePolygons = {
  "type":"FeatureCollection",
  "features":[
    {"type":"Feature",
     "properties":{
       "id":"05","name":"Tete"},
       "geometry":{"type":"Polygon",
          "coordinates":[[
          [32.636,-14.204],
          [33.245,-13.998],
          [33.299,-14.032],
          [33.300,-14.146],
          [33.385,-14.237],
          [33.478,-14.404],
          [33.544,-14.434],
          [33.627,-14.528],
          [33.640,-14.594],
          [33.718,-14.572],
          ...
```

Things I have tried:

- The data labels are SVG elements. I thought that maybe surrounding CSS rules might be affecting their position, but since the other CSS elements, using similar transformations, are in the correct locations, that doesn't seem to be the problem.
- The longitudes are negative values. I experimented with making them positive by adding +100 to each value, just to see if the negative values were to blame, but they were not. It was a long shot.
- I've played, naturally, with the API settings for data labels, but there does not seem to be a switch that affects their top-to-bottom placement. I would also think that leaving the default values untouched should result in correct placement.
- I have wondered how data labels' location is calculated by Highmaps. Perhaps Highmaps cannot find the center of each polygon and needs a hint? I added latitude and longitude values to the feature in the geojson, but that did not help. I've also used Highmaps before in a similar situation without needing to add such data.

There is a group called "highcharts-data-labels" in the generated SVG. I am considering trying the flip its coordinate system upside-down somehow to move the data labels to their correct position, but that would a complex intervention for something that should work correctly.

Please note that I am using ng-highcharts.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I stopped using ng-highcharts and used Highcharts directly to show my map. The problem went away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else running into this problem, I was able to solve this by adding the property 'chartType' to my config object. The docs for the highcharts-ng library mention this for making a highstock chart, but don't say anything about it for highmaps. The lib defaults to 'chart', but you need to put chartType: 'map', and it should fix the problem :)

Here's the relevant code from the highcharts-ng libary, where config is your chart Object:

```
var chartTypeMap = {
  'stock': 'StockChart',
  'map':   'Map',
  'chart': 'Chart'
};

function getChartType(config) {
  if (config === undefined || config.chartType === undefined) return 'Chart';
  return chartTypeMap[('' + config.chartType).toLowerCase()];
}
```

Hope this helps!